# Bootstrap validator. Regex no space

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap validator v3.1.1 and I am trying to add regexp validation for a text box.
I want to don't allow the user to introduce the space ' ', but alow to introduce letters, numers and underscore '_' in my text box. Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
           'myTextBox': {
                validators: {
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-z\s_0-9]+$/i,
                        message: 'You can introduce just alphabetical characters, underscore, number but no spaces'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me. What is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` Means "space" and you're including it in the character class, so it's allowing it. Remove it and it should be fine. Further, your regex can be just

```
regexp: /^[\w]+$/
```

as `\w = [A-Za-z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

you have `\s` which is anyspace if you want to prevent from using spaces use `\S` instead.

to be sure that you have no spaces and not test anything else you can do :

```
/^\S+$/
```

`^` = From the begining

`+` = one or more

`$` = To the end

Comment: yeah, thus this allows %^&*(#$ and many more characters which OP don't wants

Comment: true, this is only for no whitespaces.